# Regular expression for fixed string

Tags: php, regex, query-string

I have following string.

```
?page=1&sort=desc&param=5&parm2=25
```

I need to check whether the enter string url is in strict format except variable value.
Like page=, sort=, param=, param2.

Please suggest regular expression.
Thanks

Comment: Also i want variable in array array('page'=>1,'sort'=>'desc','param'=5,'param2'=25)

Comment: I think preg_match will work but i want exact regular expression

Answer (score 10):

You should use [parse_str](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) and check if all the parameters you wanted are set with `isset`. Regex is not the way to go here.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this :

```
\?page=\d+&sort=.+&param=\d+&param2=\d+
```

which translates to :

**?page=** `followed by any digit repeated 1 or more times`

**&sort=** `followed by any character repeated 1 or more times`

**&param=** `followed by any digit repeated 1 or more times`

**&param2=** `followed by any digit repeated 1 or more times`

I think Alin Purcaru 's suggestion is better

**EDIT:**

```
(\?|&)(page=[^&]+|sort=[^&]+|param=[^&]+|parm2=[^&]+)
```

This way the order doesn't matter

Comment: Yes, but order of the parameter can be change

Comment: @Rahul I don't recall you specifying that in your question

Comment: Don’t use a generic `.+` if you can use a more specific `[^&]+`.

Answer (score 0):

If you care about the order of parameters, something like this:

```
\?page=[^&]+&sort=[^&]+param=[^&]+param2=[^&]+$
```

But Alin Purcaru is right - use the parse_str function already written to do this

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following regx /\?page=[^&]*sort=[^&]*param=[^&]*param2=/` to match:

```
if (preg_match("/\?page=([^&]*)sort=([^&]*)param=([^&]*)param2=([^&]*)/i", $inputstr, $matches))
{
   echo "Matches:";
   print_r($matches);     // matches will contain the params

}
else
   echo "Params nor found, or in wrong order;
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex would be `^\?([\w\d]+=[\w\d]+(|&))*$` As long as your values are Alpha Numeric, but maybe you wanna take a look in to filters if you want to validate an url http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php